# Creating an associated object of true/false values in Rails with check_box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, associations

I'm building a Rails app for inventory tracking. When a user creates an `inventory` object, I want to create an associated `inventory_condition` object with a set of boolean values that describe different condition attributes.

```
  # schema.rb

 create_table "inventories", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "tradein_id"
    t.string   "esn"
    t.float    "price_paid"
    t.string   "erase_method"
    t.string   "status"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "device_id"
    t.string   "resale_reference"
    t.integer  "condition_id"
    t.integer  "inventory_batch_id"
  end

  create_table "inventory_conditions", force: true do |t|
    t.string  "grade"
    t.boolean "bad_esn",                   default: false, null: false
    t.boolean "find_my_iphone_locked",     default: false, null: false
    t.boolean "broken_glass",              default: false, null: false
    t.boolean "broken_lcd",                default: false, null: false
    t.boolean "broken_charge_port",        default: false, null: false
    t.boolean "broken_buttons",            default: false, null: false
    t.boolean "broken_speaker_microphone", default: false, null: false
    t.boolean "broken_camera",             default: false, null: false
    t.boolean "broken_wifi",               default: false, null: false
    t.boolean "broken_cellular",           default: false, null: false
    t.integer "inventory_id"
  end
```

In my form for creating an `inventory` object I'm having trouble passing true/false values through as params that the controller can use to build an `inventory_condition` object.

```
  # _form.html.erb (inventory)

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :functional_condition %><br>
    <% @conditions.each do |x| %>
     <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <%= check_box "[:condition]", ":#{x}", {}, "true", "false"%> <%= x.humanize.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ') %>
      </label>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

In my `inventories_controller` I build my `inventory` object in association to its parent `inventory_batch`, and then I try to create the `inventory_condition` object, which is a belongs_to child of the `inventory` class.

```
  # inventories_controller.rb

  def create
    @inventory_batch = InventoryBatch.find(params[:inventory_batch_id])

    @inventory = @inventory_batch.inventories.build(inventory_params)

    @condition = @inventory.inventory_conditions.build(inventory_conditions_params)
  end
```

When submitted, the condition parameters are:

```
":condition"=>{":bad_esn"=>"false", ":find_my_iphone_locked"=>"false", ":broken_glass"=>"true", ":broken_lcd"=>"true", ":broken_charge_port"=>"false", ":broken_buttons"=>"false", ":broken_speaker_microphone"=>"false", ":broken_camera"=>"false", ":broken_wifi"=>"false", ":broken_cellular"=>"false"}
```

Which is not suitable to pass through as `strong_params`.

Two questions:

1. Is there a better way to store these condition attributes?  I could put them right on each inventory object, but that didn't seem clean.
2. What's the proper way to create the checkbox fields and pass them through the `inventories_controller` to build my `inventory_condition` object?

**Edit - added full params when form is submitted**

```
Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"MWkzncKzxhsqn5DmyA3nRblCrTfTz3EgnF8BSKFWfjs=",
 "inventory"=>{"esn"=>"",
 "price_paid"=>"",
 "erase_method"=>"Pre-Erased",
 "inventory_conditions"=>{"bad_esn"=>"false",
 "find_my_iphone_locked"=>"false",
 "broken_glass"=>"false",
 "broken_lcd"=>"true",
 "broken_charge_port"=>"true",
 "broken_buttons"=>"false",
 "broken_speaker_microphone"=>"false",
 "broken_camera"=>"false",
 "broken_wifi"=>"false",
 "broken_cellular"=>"false"}},
 "Manufacturer"=>"",
 "Network"=>"Select the Network",
 "Model"=>"Select the Model",
 "Variant"=>"Select the Variant",
 "Capacity"=>"Select the Capacity",
 "Color"=>"Select the Color",
 "condition"=>"",
 "commit"=>"Save Inventory",
 "inventory_batch_id"=>"16"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `fields_for` method:

```
# _form.html.erb (inventory)

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :functional_condition %><br>
    <%= f.fields_for :inventory_conditions do |i| %>
     <% @conditions.each do |x| %>
      <div class="checkbox">
       <label>
        <%= i.check_box "[:condition]", "#{x}".to_sym %> <%= x.humanize.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ') %>
       </label>
     </div>
    <% end %>
   <% end %>
  </div>
```

Edit (this stuff is for the single strong params method):

That way, the `inventory_conditions` parameters are passed as a sub-hash of the `inventories` params. You need to update your strong params to include this:

```
inventory_conditions_attributes: [:broken_glass, :broken_lcd, etc...]
```

This MUST be at the end of your strong params list (i.e. after `esn`, `status`, etc).

Comment: Thanks!  When I build the new `inventory_condition` in my controller how do I access those attributes?  Like this? `@inventory.inventory_conditions.build(inventory_params[inventory_conditions_attributes])`

Comment: If inventories `has_many` inventory_conditions, yes. If it's `has_one`, then it would be `@inventory.build_inventory_conditions(...)`

Comment: Now I'm getting `undefined local variable or method inventory_conditions_att‌​ributes for #<InventoriesController:0x007f84c267d740>` when submitting the form.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the params that are submitted when you submit the form? I probably misspelled `inventory_conditions_att‌​ributes`.

Comment: Also, right now if I have any of the checkboxes checked, I get `unknown attribute: inventory_conditions`, calling on the line for building my `inventory` object.

Comment: And you do have the `has_one :inventory_conditions` in your `inventory` model, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83638/discussion-between-bnzelener-and-ryan-k).